# How to access the EBS volume on AWS via EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EBS (elastic storage) volume on AWS attached to my EC2 instance.

However, how do I make all the gigas available to that EC2 instance?

When I run

```
sudo file -s /dev/xvda
```

I get

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   80G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    8G  0 disk
```

So it looks like only the 8G part is mounted but not the whole 80G.

How do I mount the extra space?

I saw an article here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

It says I should format this volume, but as I see it has a subvolume `xvda1`, so I don't want to accidentally format everything before mounting it again.

Any idea how to make it work and mount this additional 80Giga?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this documentation page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @jellycsc reference above.

Check file formats on volumes:

```
sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
```

List block devices:

```
lsblk
```

Then change the size of the block device:

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1

// 1 is the number of the volume on the main EBS
```

Verify with:

```
lsblk
```

Then extend the file system (before was the volume).

Check:

```
df -h
```

Then check the filesystem:

```
sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
```

and apply:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```